# What is the best approach to extract a tag

Tags: php

I have this elements where I need to extract this {{search_tag}} and replace by a value

```
https://www.toto.com/search/10/{{search_tag}}.html#_his_
```

I tried this but I don't if it's the good way, does'nt work.

```
$words = explode('{{search_tag}} ',$website_url[$n]);
$exists_at = array_search($seach,$words);
if ($exists_at){
  echo "Found at ".$exists_at." key in the \$word array";
}
```

Comment: Why not something like [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = 'https://www.toto.com/search/10/{{search_tag}}.html#_his_';
$val = 'NEW_VALUE';
$new_str = str_replace("{{search_tag}}", $val, $str);
//outputs: https://www.toto.com/search/10/NEW_VALUE.html#_his_
```